# Audio playback issues and GUI programs crashing randomly

Tags: sound, python, pulseaudio, gui, window

I'm having some issues with audio playback and program crashes on Ubuntu 22.04, Pulse Audio.

I've uninstalled some random stuff that I have installed recently off of my disk (some
python stuff and flatpak stuff:

Flatpak list:

- `org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.MDA`,
- `freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.Calf`,
- `org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.ZamPlugins`,
- `org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.ZamPlugin`,
- `org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.LSP`

Python List:

- `python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine`
- `PyQtWebEngine`)

I don't know if any of that is really relevant to my question, but all I know is that a day later after I logged on to my computer, I had very strange sounds played every time I have audio played (it sounds like a lightsaber hitting something... just very amplified).

Also, applications are randomly freezing and crashing, and most apps when I open them appear in the panel to be opened, but no visible window appears and a force quit popup appears, and in order for me to open the app, I have to kill it and reopen it, and then it will also randomly freeze.

I've tried to fix the issue with the sound, (I'm using pules-audio) and nothing, and the issue with the applications I have no idea where to start with...

If anyone could help me, or even give me a direction on how I can fix this, I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

- did you reboot/restart pulseaudio (pulseaudio -k or terminate session) after the package changes ?
- check for high cpu usage
- check for high memory usage
- you might also ( instead of rebooting/re-logging in ) work with `pactl list modules` and`pactl unload-module XYZ` to see if there are zombies loaded
- maybe kill your browsers and other load-intensive apps if they are stil connected to that "killed" pulseaudio when doing these things in a running session

( no warranty, please comment if you succeeded )

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I've restarted pusleaudio and my computer many times, and nothing changed.
I see no unusual high memory and cpu usage.
I've tried `pactl list modules` and at first it didn't work, but after remove pulseaudio and try many other solutions, I got a long list of modules that i'm not sure what i'm supposed to do with them.
Also with trying many stuff I've managed to stop the playback sounding like lightsabers, but pulseaudio is having a huge delay and cuts on sounds. Pipewire-pulse is working pretty well, but it only works with system sounds, not with any applications

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with 22.04 studio using a lexicon dac.
The only way I got my sound to work corectly was to boot, wait about 2 min but no more than 7.
1st i would bring up kid3 for thats what i use for local music playback. Let it play and after 10-12 sec it would cut.
2nd once it cut unplug the usb to the dac and let the internal speakers take over. They last about 10-12 sec.
3rd after the internal would cut out then plug the dac in via usb and it would then work for practicly ever. I would do this and play music non stop for 48hrs if not 72hrs sometimes with no issues.

When i upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10 all those problems went away and i dont have to do that anymore.

On a side note if discovery had an update it would kill the audio, so do updates 1st, reboot, and then do the steps above. I know it sounds wierd and frankly it was, but after working with computers for over 35yrs nothing suprises me anymore and sometimes a little voodoo magic just works?

Good luck, i hope this helps and if it dosent at least you know you were not the only one.